# how to use import "@openzeppelin" in remix or import "https://github..." in truffle?

Tags: truffle, remix, openzeppelin

I can do `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";` in truffle and `import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";` in remix but I need a solution that works for both. I can't maintain 2 sets of files, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

> i use remixd and it does not work

Could you retry one more time, a new version has been added recently and is fixing a bunch of issues..

`npm install -g remixd`

`remixd -d ./ --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`

> and remix desktop has no way to use metamask

yeah..
Wallet connect integration will come hopefully soon https://medium.com/remix-ide/remix-ide-needs-you-to-beta-test-release-0-10-5-2a89c13ccc07

you can already test it at https://remix-alpha.ethereum.org

Answer (score 0):

```
 remixd -s C:\blah\blah\blah --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org
```

You must use -s and not -d

Answer (score -1):

If you use remix with remixd or directly remix-desktop https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases
`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";` should work

Comment: i use remixd and it does not work

Comment: and remix desktop has no way to use metamask so I'm pretty much stuck